# Work around for vector<bool>, use basic_string<bool>?

Tags: c++

Is this a safe workaround? I want to use *vector bool* but need to pass a pointer to old code expecting C-style array.

```
typedef std::basic_string<bool> vector_bool;

int main()
{
    vector_bool ab;
    ab.push_back(true);
    ab.push_back(true);
    ab.push_back(true);
    ab.push_back(false);
    bool *b = &ab[0];
    b[1] = false;
}
```

Edit:
Thanks for suggestions of other solutions, but I would really like a definite answer on my above solution. Thanks.

Comment: Does your old code want packed bits or each bool at a separately addressable location?

Comment: Each bool seperate, as a classic bool myarray[n] would be.

Comment: What about vector<char>?

Comment: and how old is the C code? are you sure C's `_Bool` type has the same representation as C++'s `bool`?

Comment: It is C++ code, but using pointers to access array data rather than stl vector and iterators.

Comment: oh sorry I misread it as "old C code" not "old code expecting C-style array"

Comment: If I use vector<char>, I cannot pass to a (bool *) parameter as it might not be the same size.

Comment: An option: Just implement a specialized class just for a dynamic array of bools.  You can keep it very simple by not worrying about allocators and just using plain `new`. Probably not more than two pages of code needed.

Comment: [The C++ committee really ought to remove the specialization of `std::vector<bool>` and provide a separate packed data structure, named something like `std::bit_vector`](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/onvectorbool.html). At least that's my thoughts. `std::vector<bool>` breaks a lot of code.

Comment: @MikeDuPont I don't want those args in main

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure about `std::basic_string<bool>` because that will instantiate `std::char_traits<bool>` and I'm not sure if the standard requires that to be defined, or if the `char_traits` primary template can be left undefined, with only explicit specializations such as `char_traits<char>` being defined.  You're not allowed to provide your own specialization of `char_traits<bool>` because you can only specialize standard templates if the specialization depends on a user-defined type, which `bool` obviously isn't.  That said, it might work if your stdlib does have a default `char_traits` definition, and you don't try to use an string operations that require members of `char_traits` to do anything useful.

Alternatively, this is hacky but might work:

```
struct boolish { bool value; };
inline boolish make_boolish(bool b) { boolish bish = { b }; return bish; }

std::vector<boolish> b;
b.push_back( make_boolish(true) );
bool* ptr = &b.front().value;
```

`boolish` is a trivial type, so as long as an array of `boolish` has the same representation as an array of `bool` (which you'd need to check for your compiler, I used a `static_assert` to check there is no padding) then you might get away with it, although it probably violates the aliasing rules because `*ptr` and `*++ptr` are not part of the same array, so incrementing the pointer doesn't point to the next `boolish::value` it points "past the end" of the previous one (even if those two locations actually have the same address, although [basic.compound]/3 does seem to say that `++ptr` does "point to" the next `bool`).

The syntax gets a bit easier with C++11, you don't need `make_boolish` ...

```
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>

struct boolish { bool value; };

int main()
{
  std::vector<boolish> vec(10);
  vec.push_back( boolish{true} );
  bool* ptr = &vec.front().value;
  assert( ptr[10] == true );
  ptr[3] = true;
  assert( vec[3].value == true );

  static_assert( sizeof(boolish) == sizeof(bool), "" );
  boolish test[10];
  static_assert( sizeof(test) == (sizeof(bool)*10), "" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have a couple of questions. First, are you sure I can safely make pointer to boolish as bool *, there will no be hidden padding? Second, my question is about whether the specific workaround I posted will work. Thanks.

Comment: @NeilKirk, answer updated with my thoughts on `basic_string<bool>`

Comment: Isnt it possible to add a few ~"operator bool" functions to the boolish struct, and make it even more conveniant?

Comment: Standard-layout guarantees the invariants here, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

From "Working Draft C++, 2012-11-02"

> **21.1 General [strings.general]**
>   1 This Clause describes components for manipulating sequences of any non-array POD (3.9) type.
>
> **21.4.1 basic_string general requirements [string.require]**
>   5 The char-like objects in a basic_string object shall be stored contiguously. That is, for any basic_string
>   object s, the identity &*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n shall hold for all values of n such that 0
>   <= n < s.size().

but

> 6 References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a basic_string sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that basic_string object:
>   — as an argument to any standard library function taking a reference to non-const basic_string as an argument.233
>   — Calling non-const member functions, except operator[], at, front, back, begin, rbegin, end, and rend.

So, you should be safe as long as you pay attention, not to call these functions, while you use the raw array somewhere else.

**Update**:

Character traits and requirements are described in **21.2 Character traits [char.traits]** and **21.2.1 Character traits requirements [char.traits.require]**. Additionally, typedefs and specializations are described in **21.2.2 traits typedefs [char.traits.typedefs]** and **21.2.3 char_traits specializations [char.traits.specializations]** respectively.

These traits are used in the Input/output library as well. So there are requirements, like `eof()` or `pos_type` and `off_type`, which don't make sense in the context of `basic_string`.

I don't see any requirement for these traits to be actually defined by an implementatin, besides the four specializations for `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t` and `wchar_t`.

Although, it worked out of the box with gcc 4.7 with your example, I defined a minimal `bool_traits` with just

```
struct bool_traits {
    typedef bool char_type;
    static void assign(char_type &r, char_type d);
    static char_type *copy(char_type *s, const char_type *p, std::size_t n);
    static char_type *move(char_type *s, const char_type *p, std::size_t n);
};
```

took the default implementation provided (gcc 4.7), and used that like

```
std::basic_string<bool, bool_traits> ab;
```

Your environment might already provide a working implementation. If not, you can implement a simple `bool_traits` or a template specialization `std::char_traits<bool>` yourself.

You can see the complete interface for character traits in the [Working Draft, PDF](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/) or at [cppreference.com - std::char_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits).

Comment: A deque will not guarantee all elements are contiguous as far as I know. Also, I am only interested in whether my proposed solution will work. Thanks.

Comment: Random access iterators, yes, but not all elements are contiguous, it stores them in "pages" so you get several contiguous blocks, not a single large contiguous block. So passing it to something expecting an array won't work. Only `vector` and `basic_string` guarantee contiguous storage

Comment: @JonathanWakely You're right, there's no mention of contiguous memory in deque, fixed.

Comment: Thank you, this is almost it!!!! Do you have any comment on the char_traits possible issue mentioned by Jonathan Wakely? I don't know anything about them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`boost::container::vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost/container/vector.html). It is exactly like `std::vector` but it's not specialized for `bool`.